# javac throw package doesn't exist but intellij can compile and run

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a following directory structure:

```
-com
  -laicode
    -class1
      -QuickSort.java
    -common
      -someclasses
  -test
    -class1
      -QuickSortTests.java
```

I want to import `QuickSort` class and classes in `common` package in `QuickSortTests`. So the code in `QuickSort.java` looks like:

```
package com.test.class1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import com.laicode.common.*;
import com.laicode.class1.QuickSort;

class QuickSortTests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array0 = null;
        QuickSort.quickSort(array0);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array0));

        int[] array1 = new int[0];
        QuickSort.quickSort(array1);
        ...
```

When I complie `QuickSortTests.java` in cmd using `javac QuickSortTests.java`, it throws an error saying:

```
QuickSortTests.java:4: error: package laicode.common does not exist
import laicode.common.*;
QuickSortTests.java:5: error: package laicode.class1 does not exist
import laicode.class1.QuickSort;
```

But in Intellij, `QuickSortTests` can run without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ already knows your source layout, and even what classes are defined in  what files.  `javac` doesn't.  There are multiple ways you could approach the problem, depending in part on where you want the compiled class files to go, but the simplest approach would probably be to make the root of your source tree your working directory, and run `javac` from there:

```
javac com/test/class1/QuickSortTests.java
```

(Or use backslashes instead of forward slashes on Windows.)

Note capitalization: I have assumed that the mismatch between the capitalization of your class names and that of the names of the files in which they reside is an error *in your question*.  If these actually do disagree in your sources then you should fix the discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks John for pointing the mistake out. It does complie now!